# How to plot histograms using d3.js from text file instead of random generation using map

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to plot histogram from the data stored in a text (.txt) file. I am trying to use the following d3.js script, the link is here: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3048450

```
<script>

var data = d3.range(1000).map(d3.randomBates(10));

var formatCount = d3.format(",.0f");

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {top: 10, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 30},
    width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .rangeRound([0, width]);

var bins = d3.histogram()
    .domain(x.domain())
    .thresholds(x.ticks(20))
    (data);

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(bins, function(d) { return d.length; })])
    .range([height, 0]);

var bar = g.selectAll(".bar")
  .data(bins)
  .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.x0) + "," + y(d.length) + ")"; });

bar.append("rect")
    .attr("x", 1)
    .attr("width", x(bins[0].x1) - x(bins[0].x0) - 1)
    .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.length); });

bar.append("text")
    .attr("dy", ".75em")
    .attr("y", 6)
    .attr("x", (x(bins[0].x1) - x(bins[0].x0)) / 2)
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(function(d) { return formatCount(d.length); });

g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

</script>
```

Now I want to get the data stored in text file without random generation as mentioned in the first line

```
var data = d3.range(1000).map(d3.randomBates(10));
```

Please suggest me how can I extract the data stored in the text file in the variable "data". Any help is appreciate.

Thanks.

Comment: What does the data in the text file look like?

Comment: [ 0.0096,  1.4176,  2.0544, ...,  2.0544,  0.0096,  0.0096], There may be 6 million of these values in comma separated format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your text could be parsed as json:

```
d3.json("data.txt",function(error,data) {

    // code that uses the var data here (could be all the histogram code if you want)
})
```

If you, for some reason want to remain true to the text format, you could remove the square brackets and use:

```
d3.text("data.txt",function(error,text) {
    var data = text.split(",");

   // code that uses the var data here     


})
```

These request functions (d3.json, d3.text) are asynchronous, so you can't use the contents of the file outside of the callback. So the portions of code using `data` and by extension `bins` must be within the callback.

Comment: Ok, now the code is working for the x axis value between 0 and 1, but in my case the x asix value is varying like from 0 to 50. So how can I modify the x axis range? Please suggest. Thanks.

Comment: You need to set the domain of your x scale : `var x = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0,50]).range(...`. The default domain is [0,1].

Comment: Ok, thank you so much. This is working now. I have used the var x as below: var x =d3.scaleLinear().domain([0,20]).range([0,1000]); which gives me the histogram as I want for the time being.